# How could I sort columns based on criteria contained in a specific row (Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I have data like the following matrix:
A = [2 5 10 4 10; 2 4 5 1 2; 6 2 1 5 4];

A =

```
 2     5    10     4    10
 2     4     5     1     2
 6     2     1     5     4
```

I would like to sort the by the last row based on the following criteria:

if the difference between the first element (in the third row) and second element (in the third row) is less than or equal to 2 -- then move that column (the second in this case two columns to the right). Then do this for all columns until no two elements (of the last row) are within a difference of 2)

B =

```
 2     5     4    10    10
 2     4     1     5     2
 6     2     5     1     4
```

Where (6-2 = 4) (2-5 = 3) (5-1 = 4) (1-4 = 3)

Ultimately difference between all elements of the last row and element next to it is greater than 2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When the difference between two columns is less or equal to 2, should the rightmost column of the columns that are compared be moved always **exactly 2 columns to the right**? A step-by-step explanation of the algorithm would help in understanding what you are attempting to do. A second example matrix could also be useful in clarifying the algorithm, as `B` can be reached from `A` with only one change: column 3 with column 4.

Comment: Starting at the leftmost column I am comparing the elements contained in the last row of data. I am comparing 6 to 2, difference of which is greater than two, so at that move to column two -- column two and three are less than -- so column two would move over to the forth column. At this point there are no two elements which differences are less than 2 so it is complete.

Comment: To clarify - the sole purpose of the algorithm is to assure that the difference between the adjacent elements in the last row are not less than or equal to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible solution:

```
A = [2 5 10 4 10; 2 4 5 1 2; 6 2 1 5 4];

B = A;

MatrixWidth = size(A, 2);

CurIndex = 1;

%# The second-last pair of the bottom row is the last pair to be compared.
while(CurIndex+2 <= MatrixWidth)
    Difference = abs(A(3,CurIndex) - A(3,CurIndex+1));

    %# If the right side of comparison is not yet the second-last index.
    if ((Difference <= 2) && (CurIndex+3 <= MatrixWidth))
        B = [ B(:, 1:CurIndex), B(:, CurIndex+2), B(:, CurIndex+1), B(:, CurIndex+3:end) ];
    %# If the right side of the comparison is already the second-last index.
    elseif (Difference <= 2)
        B = [ B(:, 1:CurIndex), B(:, CurIndex+2), B(:, CurIndex+1) ];
    end

    CurIndex = CurIndex + 1;
end
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark this as accepted answer (a green "accepted" mark becomes visible) if this solution works for you.

Comment: It's the empty (only contours visible) v-formed symbol below upvote/downvote buttons in the upper-left part of an answer (and obviously you need to be logged in). Upon accepting the answer, the color of the symbol changes to green.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. This is the first time I've used this site.

Comment: I was looking for an idea like this for a .net project. Thank you!